# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined (also 'startWith')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The error I'm getting: (I also get the same error with 'startWith'). I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm not really a pro at all of this so I need some help. Thank you

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at module.exports.message (/root/dvstin.xyz/events/message.js:6:21)
at Client.client.on.args (/root/dvstin.xyz/druggy2.js:14:39)
at Client.emit (events.js:187:15)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (/root/dvstin.xyz/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:137:47)
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
module.exports = message => {
// Define client
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = message.client;
// Check who, and the prefix being used

if (message.author.id === "") return;
if (!message.content.startsWith(client.settings.prefix)) return;
// Define command
const command = message.content
    .split(" ")[0]
    .slice(client.settings.prefix.length)
    .toLowerCase();
// Define command paramaters
const params = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
let cmd;
if (client.commands.has(command)) {
    cmd = client.commands.get(command);
}
// If command, run that command
if (cmd) {

    cmd.run(client, message, params);

}

};
```

Comment: Means `message.author` is undefined. Debug it and see what message contains.

Answer (score 1):

The error what you are seeing is because `message` does not have `author` or `content` field.

Handle the scenarios as below:

```
module.exports = message => {
   // Define client
   const Discord = require("discord.js");
   const client = message.client;

   console.log(message); // <--- Check this console. 
   // Check who, and the prefix being used

    if (message && message.author && message.author.id === "") return;
        if (message && message.content && !message.content.startsWith(client.settings.prefix)) return;
            // Define command
            const command = message.content
                .split(" ")[0]
                .slice(client.settings.prefix.length)
                .toLowerCase();
            // Define command paramaters
            const params = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
            let cmd;
             if (client.commands.has(command)) {
            cmd = client.commands.get(command);
        }
        // If command, run that command
        if (cmd) {

            cmd.run(client, message, params);
        }

    };
```

See the code from where it is sending the `message` and try to debug why it is not sending expected fields.

Comment: Thank you so much! However I'm still getting an error, but on a different line.
/root/dvstin.xyz/events/message.js:13
                .split(" ")[0]
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: @Universal as I have told in my answer, please check the `message` object from where is is coming and why it is not giving you all the expected fields.

Answer (score 1):

When validate a field of an object, ALWAYS you should check THE object.

Next, a example of your code.

In: `if (message.author.id === "") return;`

You should do: `if (message.author && message.author.id === "") return;`

And if you're not sure which message is not null, then you must do: 
`if (message && message.author && message.author.id === "") return;`

I hope to be helpful

Comment: Thank you so much!